# Error while sending attachment with email after publishing the site

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I want to send a text file as an attachment with email. When I run my code on local development server it runs properly and file gets attached. But when I publish the site on server, it doesn't pick the attachment and the mail is also not sent. Its not an issue of sending mails, because I have checked it by sending mail without attachment and the mail is sent. The problem is only while attaching file. I have written the path for text file attachment as

```
string filepath=@"E:\Pwavel\Attachfile\" + filename; 
Attachment MyAttachment = new Attachment(filepath);
objmsg.Attachments.Add(MyAttachment);
```

I have also created "Pwavel" and "Attachfile" folders in `E:` drive of server.
Is there a problem in path? Or any permission issue? I am not able to understand what the problem is. Please Help me...

Comment: Did you gave read access to that folder for IIS_IUSRS group?

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are working on your development machine then this does sound very much like a permission issue.

If you have the authority I'd suggest going to your Attachfile folder and adding Read permission for "Everyone", just to test. If this works you can target specific user / permissions depending on what version of IIS you are using by looking at this:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Hope this helps.